# Tourist Visa B1/B2

Tags: visas, usa, indian-citizens, b1-b2-visas, tourist-visas

Hi I am from India and have B1 . Can I come to US without a B2 visa. I had previously used this visa for official purpose. Will there be any problem relating to immigration. I will be staying with my friend what other formality do I have to do?

Comment: R U sure it's a B1 not B1/B2?

Comment: Yes it is B1/B2

Comment: Can I travel as a tourist on that visa??

Answer (score 1):

Since it's a B1/B2 visa, you can use it to enter for tourist (B2) purposes.