# US business visa related doubts

Tags: visas, usa, customs-and-immigration, indian-citizens, b1-b2-visas

I would be applying for a US Business visa to attend a [Salesforce conference](http://dreamforce.com) in San Francisco. I refer to [business visa FAQ](http://www.immihelp.com/business-visa/) from US immigration but it doesn't answer my following doubts.

- I will get a Visa Invitation letter from Salesforce based on which I will receive the visa. Does it restrict my port of entry and exit to San Francisco?
- The conference is only for 4-5 days. Would it cause any issues if I travel a week before the conference or a week later after the conference? I have plans to visit other customers in different cities (Seattle, New York)  as well as roam around few places with my wife.
- I would also like for my wife and son to accompany me. They would be on tourist visa offcourse. Are they special considerations/points that should be aware of?
- On visa receipt, is it mandatory for me to travel to US within a certain period of time? There is a slight chance I might not travel this year so can I use the visa next year? I believe visa validity is for 10 years.

Details about me:

- Country of residence and citizenship: India
- Have travelled to US twice before on L1B visa.
- Own a consulting business that works with customers using Salesforce.com

Comment: Country of citizenship?

Comment: Also, while 10 year B1/B2 visas do exist, they are not the only type, and relativley unlikley to be granted to a first time applicant.

Comment: @CMaster Mentioned in the question; I am from India. Does that the fact I have travelled to US twice on L1B visa help in getting B1/B2 visa?

Comment: You mentioned residence in the q, not citizenship. Editing to clarify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of questions in 1 but let's go in order:

1. Your port of entry to the US doesn't have to be San Francisco if your visa is granted.  You can enter at any border crossing.
2. As long as your visa is valid you should be able to enter the US.  See: 
   [Travelling to the US on B1 visa without a business purpose](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/41731/travelling-to-the-us-on-b1-visa-without-a-business-purpose?rq=1) for more information.
3. Your wife's visa is a separate concern altogether and should be addressed as such.  Your tourist (B1 or B1/B2) visa doesn't entitle your to bring anyone other than yourself to the US, so her visit will probably be addressed separately from yours.
4. Depending on the visa validity period you should be able to travel at any point during that validity period.  I am sure there was a question here about it but I can't find it at the moment.

Comment: http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/43657/3221

Comment: Thanks. Need a clarification for point 1. If the invitation letter mentions conference in SFO, am I still allowed to travel first to New York and then to SFO? Also, I understand that the visas for Me and Wife will be separate. However, should we be applying together and going for an interview or should that be separate?

Comment: @RajeshShah at the end of the day, you will always face a landing interview where you have to convince the border officer that you are a genuine visitor, and not a migrant. Having on hand your tickets/reservations for a flight to SFO and hotels there may help.